# Magento2 How to disable Price Filter/ Price Navigation

Tags: magento2

There is this block of `layered-filter-block` where it shows price filter on the right side of the category page. How can I remove it? For the time being i hid it with css.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable it from admin.

> Admin >> Store >> Product >> Select Price Attribute >> Storefront
>   Properties >> Use in Layered Navigation

Set Use in Layered Navigation as "**No**"

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now Price filter remove from layer navigation.